# Angular Js Security Issues Role Based Authorisation

Tags: angularjs, security, authorization, user-roles, client-side-scripting

I am creating a new Enterprise Application in Angular for my Company. I am very excited about angular but handling Roles on Client side is not working out for me.

Basically I am saving a token when ever the user log's in and before a user could view a page an Authorisation request is sent to the server to get the Role and User details based on the Token.

After authorisation a request to get the data for the page to the server which  returns the entire data irrespective of the Role of the user, after that I use ng-switch and render templates according to the Role.

Now the problem here is that  I am trying to show and hide data on the Client side so after I recieve the user information I have to keep the Role in some Scope variable or local Storage anywhere on the Client side. But my point here is that if I keep it on Client side I can very easily change the Role and access any data I want.

So should I assume that Angular is not fit for my app where I am trying to display data on client side according to the roles from the server because what I feel is that if user can see your logic and data he can obviously play with it.

**This is my View**

```
   <div ng-switch="User.data.Role">
       <div ng-switch-when="Admin">
            <h1>hello you are seeing your dashboard Admin</h1>
        </div>

        <div ng-switch-when="Manager">
            <h1>hello you are seeing your dashboard Manager</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Here is how I fill User variable  in Controller**

```
app.controller('dashoBoardController',  ['$scope','UserService', function ($scope, UserService) {

    $scope.authentication = UserService.authentication;
    $scope.User = UserService.fillAuthData();
    console.log($scope.User);
    $scope.Greeting = "Welcome! to your Dashboard";



}]);
```

**This is the Service method**

```
   var _fillAuthData = function () {

        var authData = SessionService.get('user');

        if (authData) {
            _authentication.isAuth = true;
            _authentication.data = authData;

        }

        console.log(_authentication);
        return _authentication;
    }
```

Session Service is getting the User data from server on the basis of token.
As you can see since the view is so descriptive changing the role in authData is not a big deal.

Please help me if there is a work around for this. I really wanted to this project in Angular.

Comment: As a general rule, the service should send back only the data that the user is authorized to see. In other words, security should be handled by the service and not the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the web service (run on the server) returns data to the client that the authenticated user is not authorized to access, then the web service (server side) has a security flaw. There is no way you can fix that client/browser side, regardless of which client side framework you decide to chose. AngularJS is probably fine for whatever you want to do in the browser, but your web service is broken.

Comment: thank you for the prompt response..but the only reason why we are trying to send the unauthorized data is because we do not want to do all the  heavy weight lifting on the server rather we want to do all the heavy manipulation on the client side so that our API can have more generic methods taking less time, as rendering JSON is faster than making database calls..Do you think creating the application with knockout and MVC in asp.net would be more efficient with the same API logic as we can have better security control over there?

Comment: No, if the *API logic* of the web server you refer to has a security flaw, then switching to another browser side framework will not fix it. A decent browser debugger will even show you the network responses (clear text JSON returned by the server), including the data you wish to hide (e.g, CTRL+SHIFT+J in Chrome -> Network tab).

Comment: Downvote here. I think the question is valid in this context because it's related to roles. It doesn't matter if the server is returning data it shouldn't. Even if it isn't, if you use roles inside a template to say "this is shown if the user is admin" then it's easy to manipulate yourself into being admin and seeing what the admin sees. The question is of course, what that is if the data is missing. But I feel uneasy about it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with nomve, the server side's security is not the problem here. Server side's security should always be the last gate for security and should always be implemented with great care.

However, being able to hack the role on the client side and see the interfaces that a user should not be able to see, even without data being drawn from the server, is not the best experience.

Checking the role every time remotely and does not store the role locally solves the problem, but it costs. Is there a native way to encrypt the role information and make hacking the role on the client side harder?